# error no rescources that matches the given name (at "label" with value "@string/about_title"

Tags: java, android

hey guys im following the Sudoku tutorial in Hello Android the 3ed edition and i cant get rid of this error, here are my files

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="org.example.sudoku"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Sudoku"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
<activity android:name=".About"
android:label="@string/about_title" >
</activity>


    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

</manifest>
```

strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Sudoku</string>
    <string name="main_title">Android Sudoku</string>
    <string name="continue_label">Continue</string>
    <string name="new_game_label">New Game</string>
    <string name="about_label">About</string>
    <string name="about_text">\
Sudoku is a logic-based number placement puzzle.
Starting with a partially completed 9x9 grid, the
objective is to fill the grid so that each row, 
each column, and each of the 3x3 boxes contains 
the digits
1 to 9 exactly once.
</string>
    <string name="exit_label">Exit</string>
</resources>
```

about.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ScrollView
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:padding="10dip" >
     <TextView
     android:id="@+id/about_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/about_text" />
     </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, the error says it all. You are referencing a string with id `about_title`, but such a string isn't defined in strings.xml. Perhaps, you could change this to `about_label`, which is indeed defined.

Answer (score 3):

you don't have `about_title` string in your string.xml. Just add it, and it will be fine. Did you mean `about_label`?

Answer (score -2):

I've had the same problem. Remove `"@string"` and works fine.

```
android:label="@string/about_title"  ->  android:label="about_title"
```

Comment: This will make the label value "about_title", which is not what the question asker wants :)